# How to bin a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, binning

numpy.histogram(data, bins) is a very fast and efficient way to calculate how many elements of the data array fall in a bin defined by the array bins. Is there an equivalent function to solve the following problem?. I have a matrix with R rows times C columns. I want to bin each row of the matrix using the definition given by bins. The result should be a further matrix with R rows, and with the number of column equal to the number of bins.

I tried to use the function numpy.histogram(data, bins) giving as input a matrix, but I found that the matrix is treated as an array with R*C elements. Then, the result is an array with Nbins elements.

Comment: also; can we take a step back? chances are you don't really need np.histogram, but that simpler but faster computations would suffice. what is your larger goal with this?

Comment: Hi Eelco, thanks for your question. I am trying to write a very fast code to manage data series. Each series for each row in my matrix. I make some operations before to arrive to the final series. In contrast with my expectations, I found that performing all these operations in a loop for each row is much slower than making the operations one by one on the full matrix. Now, at the end of these operations, I want to bin each data series. Still, I have not found a way to avoid a `for` loop to bin them.

Comment: Currently, my code run in 8 sec, of which 5 sec are taken by the binning. If I can reduce the time of the binning to the time of the other single operations (<1sec), I would greatly improve my code.  `np.histogram` is just the way I am using now, and I was surprised to see that it treats a matrix just as a flat array, rather than to maintain its structure. Of course, as you say, if there is a simpler but faster way, it would be great.

Comment: That does not really answer if you really need the binning; but as I asked below, are you sure the looping is the issue? perhaps the binning itself is simply that expensive; it is after all a much more expensive operation than most standard arithmetic array manipulations. The fact that the solution by Bi Rico is apparently even slower, suggest this may be the case, because that code appears pretty optimal to me. The only thing I can think of is that maybe you have very many very short rows, in which case a more optimal solution may exist.

Comment: I just answered your question below. Currently, I am working with data series with ~10E4 elements each.

Comment: and the number of rows is 4000, but when running on the whole dataset could be 2 order of magnitude larger.

Comment: In that case, I don't think much more can be done. One python iteration is insignificant compared to making a histogram of 10e4 elements. You could try writing a numba extension to create a faster histogram perhaps.

Comment: I need to think further about the really need of the binning. But perhaps sorting the data and the indexing cold be a solution. IN this case I need to know the index corresponding to the edges of the bins. In other words, the index of the largest element within a bin.

Comment: This is what the searchsorted command in Bi Rico 's solution does. It does a binary search so is pretty efficient

Answer (score 2):

If you're applying this to an array that has *many rows* this function will give you some speed up at the cost of some temporary memory.

```
def hist_per_row(data, bins):

    data = np.asarray(data)

    assert np.all(bins[:-1] <= bins[1:])
    r, c = data.shape
    idx = bins.searchsorted(data)
    step = len(bins) + 1
    last = step * r
    idx += np.arange(0, last, step).reshape((r, 1))
    res = np.bincount(idx.ravel(), minlength=last)
    res = res.reshape((r, step))
    return res[:, 1:-1]
```

The `res[:, 1:-1]` on the last line is to be consistent with numpy.histogram which returns an array with len `len(bins) - 1`, but you could drop it if you want to count values that are less than and greater than `bins[0]` and `bins[-1]` respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I copied your function, but got the following message: `res = np.bincount(idx.ravel(), minlength=last)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

Comment: @user3242568, my guess is that you're using the `numpy.matrix` type instead of the `numpy.ndarray` type. You can read about the two data types [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935). If that's the case the fix is easy, just wrap `data` in a call to `np.asarray`. I've updated the answer.

On a side note, I would just about always recommend using `ndarray` over `matrix`, because `matrix` just breaks stuff more than anything else. But you know, some people like to make their lives more difficult :).

Comment: With the new line the code now works, but I am sorry to say that it is even slower then the `for` loop. I am calculating the CPU time with `time.clock()`. I do not know if there is a better way.

Comment: You can use the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), or if you happen to be using ipython you can use the [%timeit magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html?highlight=timeit#IPython.core.magics.execution.ExecutionMagics.timeit).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everybody for your answers and comments. Finally, I found a way to speed up the binning procedure. Instead of using `np.searchsorted(data)`, I am doing `np.array(data*nbins, dtype=int)`. Substituting this line in the code posted by Bi Rico, I found that it becomes a factor 3 faster. Here below I post the function by Bi Rico with my modification, so that other user can easily take it.

```
def hist_per_row(data, bins):

    data = np.asarray(data)
    assert np.all(bins[:-1] <= bins[1:])
    r, c = data.shape

    nbins = len(bins)-1
    data = data/bins[-1]
    idx = array(data*nbins, dtype=int)+1

    step = len(bins) + 1
    last = step * r
    idx += np.arange(0, last, step).reshape((r, 1))
    res = np.bincount(idx.ravel(), minlength=last)
    res = res.reshape((r, step))
    return res[:, 1:-1]
```

Comment: that's my I asked for a little more context; apparently your bins are all equally spaced, while the wording of your question suggests the contrary. as a note to other users (and perhaps yourself if you are not aware), directly mapping to ints and using bincount only works for equally spaced bins

Comment: Yes, sure. Sorry for not having mentioned before I was working with equally spaced bins

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(10,20)
print np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.histogram(x)[0], 1, data)
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the hint. The forms below perfectly match my needs: `print np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.histogram(x, bins)[0], 1, data)`

Comment: Anyway, substituting this line with the loop on the matrix rows I had on my code, I find that the CPU time is unchanged. I was hoping in something faster than a 'for' loop.

Comment: @user3242568 `np.apply_along_axis` still does all of its looping in Python, so it's essentially just a syntactically neater way of doing a conventional `for` loop

Comment: Indeed, seems you (ali_m) are perfectly right. But, I noticed that for example a multiplication between two matrix performed writing `matrixA*matrixB` is much faster than performing the same operation with an explicit `for` loop on columns and rows. I was wondering if for the binning there is an operation similarly fast as the multiplication in the example above.

Comment: are you sure the looping is your problem, and not np.histogram itself? python looping may be slow, but still, unless your rows are really short, that cost is easily amortized.

Comment: Hi again Eelco. Maybe you are right. I just checked that giving as input to `np.histogram` the full matrix (`np.histogram(matrixA, bins)[0]`), rather than making a loop on each row (`for i in range(N): np.histogram(matrixA[i], bins)[0]`) the computational time is the same. Then, every suggestion is welcome.