# Python: Count no of elements from list of list and feed to Matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, counter, python-xarray

Given a list of list's, where each list is of the length

```
 M = [[1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2,9,0], [3,2,1,0,5,6,2,4,6,7], [4,5,5,2,1,2,3,4,2,4], [7,5,6,2,6,7,8,8,8,1] ]
```

I want to count the number of repetition's of an element and feed it into a separate matrix.

Let's call each list as a `frame` and  elements in a frame as `states`.

Here is my code and it works fine:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
from xarray import DataArray

def Vfinal(s_t,Matrix):
    state_no = np.arange(0,s_t)
    frame_no = np.arange(0,len(Matrix))                  
    V= DataArray(np.zeros(( len(state_no),len(Matrix) )), coords=[('States_count', state_no), ('Frame',frame_no)])
    for i,j in enumerate(Matrix):
        for k in j:
            print(k,i)
            V.loc[k,i] +=1
    return  V

In [172]: V = Vfinal(10,M)

In [173]: V
Out[173]:
<xarray.DataArray (States_count: 10, Frame: 4)>
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
Coordinates:
  * States_count  (States_count) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  * Frame         (Frame) int64 0 1 2 3
```

In my case the list `M` has `28,800 lists`, where each list contains 75 elements (numbers between 0 to 499).

This makes the matrix a size of 500X 28,800. The code takes 30 minutes (approx) to finish and **I believe the problem lies in the `for` loop.**

Is there any efficient way of writing it so that the code can be executed faster?

Comment: Can you please remove the `print(k,i)` from the loop and time it again. Writing each iteration usually takes too much time

Comment: Yes I removed and even it takes more time .

Comment: It is slower without the `print`?!? That makes no sense. Anyway, I think your question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394626/how-to-bin-a-matrix , please check if the answer there helps you

Comment: No, It doesnt help me very particularly .

Comment: I copied and tried your code with randomly generated data of the shape you mention (28800x75) and (without the print) it took around 3s, and the method from the question I suggested took around 0.2s. Are you sure this is the part that is slowing down your code?

Comment: Ok, Did each list has 75 elements and the elements are the numbers between 0 to 500 ? i.e `M = [ M[0],M[1],.,]`. 'M[0]` length is 75 and it has values between 0 to 500 and `len(M)`=28800. This makes a matrix of size 500 X 28800.

Comment: Yes, I created M as `M=np.random.randint(500, size=(28800, 75))`, and the output V is of shape (500 x 28800). I just tried the new version you posted, and it takes ~1.5s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the function `Vfinal` to `Vfinal2`.

This makes the code faster

```
def Vfinal2(s_t,Matrix):
        V = np.zeros((s_t,len(Matrix)))
        for i,row in enumerate(Matrix):
            a = np.bincount(row)
            b=np.zeros(s_t)
            b[:len(a)]=a
            V[:,i]=b
    return V
```